# Problems with positioning a lightbox

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a lightbox that should be preferably based on a minimal amount of JS (frameworks, however "light" they may be, are *not* allowed). With the help of various resources, I wrote the following bit of JS:

```
var dialogWritten = false;

function getZIndex(elem) {
    var elems = document.getElementsByTagName(elem);
    var highest = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        var zindex = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(elems[i], null).getPropertyValue("z-index");
        if ((zindex > highest) && (zindex != 'auto')) {
            highest = zindex;
        }
    }
    return highest;
}

function displayDialog() {
    if (!dialogWritten) {
        var backgroundOverlay = document.createElement("div");
        backgroundOverlay.style.display = "block";
        backgroundOverlay.style.position = "absolute";
        backgroundOverlay.style.top = "0%";
        backgroundOverlay.style.left = "0%";
        backgroundOverlay.style.width = "100%";
        backgroundOverlay.style.height = "100%";
        backgroundOverlay.style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
        backgroundOverlay.style.zIndex = getZIndex('*') + 1;
        backgroundOverlay.style.opacity = "0.8";
        document.body.appendChild(backgroundOverlay);
        dialogWritten = true;

        var configDialog = document.createElement("div");
        configDialog.style.display = "block";
        configDialog.style.position = "absolute";
        configDialog.style.top = "25%";
        configDialog.style.left = "25%";
        configDialog.style.width = "50%";
        configDialog.style.height = "50%";
        configDialog.style.backgroundColor = "#acacac";
        configDialog.style.zIndex = getZIndex('*') + 1;
        configDialog.style.padding = "10px";
        configDialog.style.fontFace = "sans-serif";
        configDialog.innerHTML = '<p>Configuration dialog</p>';
        document.body.appendChild(configDialog);
        dialogWritten = true;
    }
}
```

The lightbox apparently works, but it turns out that the overlay applies only to the topmost part of the page, not to the lower sections.

Screenshots will help make the description clear:

[image: screenshot: Lightbox applies to the above part]
[image: screenshot: Lightbox does not apply to lower sections]

What should I do in order to make the overlay of the lightbox apply to the whole of the page?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what you want to achieve - do you want the lightbox position to be fixed (relative to the viewport)? If that is the case, it is simple - just set position to fixed instead of absolute.

**Edit after OP clarification:**

If you want the lightbox overlay to apply to the whole page, set the background overlay's position to fixed.

Comment: I want the overlay of the lightbox to be applied to the whole page. The question did not make this clear, edited to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
backgroundOverlay.style.position = "absolute";
```

to

```
backgroundOverlay.style.position = "fixed";
```

and

```
configDialog.style.position = "absolute";
```

to

```
configDialog.style.position = "fixed";
```